# Can't move mouse pointer to other screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, 19.04

I can't move mouse pointer to another monitor. I have 3 monitor setup this output might contain some useful information:

```
pc:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   (... Removed output just to decrease in size)
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   (... Removed output just to decrease in size)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   (... Removed output just to decrease in size)
```

I have install new Kubuntu:

```
pc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

This is how it looks I can see some part of mouce on another screen but it just doesn't continue to move.

[image]

Comment: In my case two monitors are black, one is active. When I move mouse cursor to the edge, I see cursor appearing in a neighbor black monitor, but it can't move further.